# How to install specific extensions for PHP 5.5

Tags: software-installation, mysql, php

I need to install a few specific extensions into a PHP 5.5.9 instance. The version of PHP can't be updated because it is mirroring a production environment.

I tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5-curl php5-mysql php5-mysqli php5-pdo_mysql
```

but only cURL got installed. It can't find the other extensions.

How can I get the MySQL extensions installed for PHP 5.5.9?

Comment: Try to install packages with prefix `php5.6-`. I think packages for earlier versions are not available. But there is a change the 5.6 will work.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz The last thing I want to do is debug weird production issues because the test environment is not set up identically. I'm not even certain 5.6 extensions will work with 5.5. I've always had to use exactly matching versions in the past.